# jquery empty value on select form - should I use false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

Ok,

So I have a dropdown `<select>` that has the first `<option>` selected with an empty value. I have jquery evaluate if it is not empty and redirect to url. However, what should I do if it is empty?

```
$('#cat').on('change', function() {
    $(this).val() != '' ? location.assign('http://www.example.com/' + $(this).val()) : false;
});
```

The above example works. If I use `return false` or `return(false)` or just leaving the second ternary value empty ``, I get an error message: `expected expression, got keyword 'return'` or `expected expression, got ';'`.

What is the correct way to terminate that ternary evaluation for empty values? Using just `false` gives no console errors and seems to work fine.

Comment: just use null instead of false;

Comment: I'm guessing that's EsLint complaining. Add `return` in the front to set ternary operator as an expression. `return ($(this).val()) !== '' ? : ;`

Comment: @Davion - no just firefox console.

Comment: @DinoMyte ok will do that. mark as answer.